# InstantiationException when doing functional testing with Guice

Tags: java, testing, playframework, guice

I'm trying to do `Guice` testing of my controllers in `Play framework 2.4.6`.
The following code works fine:

```
public class GeneralTest {
    @Inject
    Application application;
    private final AccountService accountServiceMock = mock(AccountService.class);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Module testModule = new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(AccountService.class).toInstance(accountServiceMock);
            }
        };

        GuiceApplicationBuilder builder = new GuiceApplicationLoader()
                .builder(new ApplicationLoader.Context(Environment.simple()))
                .overrides(testModule);
        Guice.createInjector(builder.applicationModule()).injectMembers(this);

        Helpers.start(application);
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        Helpers.stop(application);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws SQLException {
        RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder()
                .uri(routes.LoginController.login().url());

        running(application, () -> {
            assertEquals(OK, route(request).status());
        });
    }


    @Test
    public void testCreateAccount() throws SQLException {
        RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder()
                .uri(routes.CreateController.createAccount().url());

        running(application, () -> {
            assertEquals(OK, route(request).status());
        });
    }   
}
```

However, when I tried to organize my methods, separating `testLogin()` and `testCreateAccount` into 2 test classes which consist of exact same `@Before` and `@After`, I'm getting `InstantiationException`, seemingly on any classes that execute after the first, occurring on the line of `RequestBuilder`:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: controllers.CreateController, took 2.656 sec
[error]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[error]     at play.api.inject.NewInstanceInjector$.instanceOf(Injector.scala:49)
[error]     at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$15$$anonfun$apply$87.apply(Routes.scala:534)
[error]     at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$15$$anonfun$apply$87.apply(Routes.scala:534)
[error]     at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
[error]     at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:70)
[error]     at play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
[error]     at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:108)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:108)
[error]     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:107)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(Unknown Source)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: controllers.CreateController.<init>()
[error]     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
[error]     ... 36 more
```

I'm following the documentations here, which doesn't show the setup with multiple classes:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTestingWithGuice https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**
The reason is simply that Play is executing tests in parallel. To ensure that they are executing serially, put `parallelExecution in Global := false` in `build.sbt`.

If you don't want to use global scope, you can change the scope axis:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+configuration+axis

The following code is then completely **not** needed:

```
running(application, () -> {
}
```